# Extra padding is added in mozilla for content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-lists, mozilla

Below is my code:

```css
#sam_ul li {
  height: 41px;
  border-bottom: 1pt solid #DEDEDE;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
#sam_ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#u_l_add:before {
  content: '\0FBF';
}
```

```html
<ul id="sam_ul" style="margin:0px;">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span id="u_l_add" style="font-size:36px;line-height:20px;"></span>
      <div style="width:130px;position:relative;top:-20px;left:40px;">Add</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span id="u_l_sear" style="font-size:36px;line-height:20px;"></span>
      <div style="width:130px;position:relative;top:-20px;left:40px;">Search Artifact</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The **content pseudo element** is displayed differently in both IE and mozilla. By different I mean in `IE` it is displaying correctly while in mozilla it is adding some extra padding and displaying the content.

check the difference between the first `li` element and the second `li` element.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: reset element styles before adding is the best way to avoid browser specific styles. Try to include margin & padding to "0" for block level elements like p, div, heading tags, ul, ol, li, ......

Comment: When you say "mozilla" do you mean "Firefox" are you really using [Mozilla Suite](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/products/mozilla1.x/)?

Comment: I mean firefox ..not the mozilla suite..

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding:0` to [unordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)

```css
#sam_ul{
    padding:0
    }
#sam_ul li {
    height: 41px;
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #DEDEDE;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    list-style-type: none; 
}

#u_l_add:before {
    content: '\0FBF'; }

#u_l_sear:before {
    content: '\0FBF'; }
```

```html
<body>
<ul id="sam_ul" style="margin:0px;">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <span id="u_l_add" style="font-size:36px;line-height:20px;"></span>
            <div style="width:130px;position:relative;top:-20px;left:40px;">Add</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <span id="u_l_sear" style="font-size:36px;line-height:20px;"></span>
                <div style="width:130px;position:relative;top:-20px;left:40px;">Search Artifact</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks.. but the problem still persists.. can you once run this code snippet both in mozilla and IE.. you will know the difference.. [ I am using IE8 ].

Comment: on firefox and chrome (macosx) it is working fine for me i am not using a PC sorry. What about posting some screenshots?

Comment: Sorry .. but only people with 10 reputation can upload the images..  so cant upload them

Answer (score 0):

Try to normalize everything. HTML and body has default margin and padding for every browser that could ruin your design. Almost all block elements has that.

Try:

```
html,body{
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}
```

Or download and add normalize.css

Comment: still the same..
the problem is with the content that is being displayed with the pseudo element :before..
if I remove that pseudo element that the display is working fine, but I want the pseudo element to be displayed.

Comment: Hey, why not try using ::before instead of :before. I found out that ':' is for styling and '::' for structural changes.

Comment: but ::before isn't completely supported by `IE8` also the problem is still present even after replacing in mozilla..